# Why is TextRenderer.MeasureText inaccurate here?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to draw a margin at 80 characters in my TextBox subclass.  Here is my code:

```
class FooTextBox : TextBox
{
    ...

    void UpdateMarginPosition()
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics()) {
            int charWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, "M", Font,
                ClientSize, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding).Width;

            const int LeftMargin = 2;
            margin.Left = charWidth * 80 + LeftMargin;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for certain fonts at certain sizes (e.g., Courier New at size 10):

[image]

But with other fonts this turns out to be slightly inaccurate.  Here is a screenshot with Consolas at size 12, for example:

[image]

As you can see, the line cuts through the 0, when instead it should be to the right of the 0.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that 'margin' is a WinForms.Label.

Comment: Guess you will have to play with different `TextFormatFlags`.

Comment: First thing to rule out is whether its the constant or the multiplication. If you set it to 40, does it overlap the end character by the same amount? If so, then obviously `LeftMargin` needs some adjustment.

Comment: Damien:  If I say `margin.Left = charWidth + LeftMargin;`, I have the same problem:  Courier New is fine, but Consolas is not.

Comment: So where did the magic value of `2` for `LeftMargin` come from? How was it determined?

Comment: Why are you changing the margins of a `Label`?  You derive from `Textbox` so I would assume you want the `Textbox` to change.  What is the `Label` for?

Comment: Btw, why the is the result not `SizeF`. Not all rendering of font sizes are 'pixel perfect'. Edit: I see it does not support that.

Comment: SwDevMan81:  Sorry, I wrote 'Label' when I had intended to write 'Panel'.  I edited the message.

Comment: @Tom: I am editing this post to show the images within the post. You can still click on them to get a larger version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem.  I had to get the left margin of the TextBox by sending EM_GETMARGINS (rather than just assuming that the left margin is 2, which works for only some fonts/sizes), and I had to do this *after* `base.OnFontChanged(e);` in my OnFontChanged override.  Thanks, all, for the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Graphics.MeasureString` instead. The result is `SizeF` and not `Size` like the TextRenderer's method returns.

Comment: I get the same problem (Courier New is different from Consolas) if I use "SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(new string('m', 80), Font);".

Comment: IIRC, you need some specific StringFormat settings. Will look for code I wrote years back to handle this.

Comment: Thanks.  I seem to have solved the problem now, as mentioned in my answer to this question.

Comment: My font size was `10.5f`, so using `TextRenderer.MeasureText` was giving an incorrect `Width`. `Graphics.MeasureString` gave the correct value. -- in the end, I changed the font size to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

But, you should use just fixed length font, because width of char 'I' is different than width of char 'M'. Or if you know string in textbox. You can change code:

```
int stringWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, this.text, Font,
            ClientSize, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding).Width;

        margin.Left = stringWidth;
```

Comment: Courier New and Consolas *are* fixed-width fonts, so this comment doesn't answer the question.

Comment: ClientSize and TextFormatFlags.NoPadding are key arguments here, without them - measuring doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try just setting the [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width.aspx)

```
Width = charWidth * 80 + LeftMargin;
```

I created a derived class from `TextBox` that will auto size the width based on the Text.  It works with both fonts you mentioned:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
   public override string Text
   {
      get
      {
         return base.Text;
      }
      set
      {
         base.Text = value;
         UpdateTextboxWidth();
      }
   }

   void UpdateTextboxWidth()
   {
      using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
      {
         int text_width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, base.Text, Font,
             ClientSize, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding).Width;

         Width = text_width + Margin.Left + Margin.Right;
      }
   }
}
```

Note: In my project, the `Margin.Left` and `Margin.Right` are set to 3

Comment: The Width of what?  I can't just set the Width of the TextBox, as I'm creating a right margin, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: So you want a Left and Right margin of equal size?  Maybe a screen shot of what you want would be helpful

Comment: I want a right margin only.  "LeftMargin" is the TextBox's natural left margin.  I've now included a screenshot with Courier New at size 10, which shows how things should look.